# I already load my session but it show undefined

Tags: php, jquery, session, codeigniter-3

```
class Googleplus extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('javascript');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('email');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('login') == true){
            redirect('welcome/profile');
        }
    }
```

when I run my code it show session error Message: `Undefined property: Googleplus::$session`

Filename: controllers/Googleplus.php

Comment: Where you started the session? Give us the var_dump of $_SESSION

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: Both of you can see that session is started (loaded session library) on line 4.

Comment: This shows where you're checking the session property, but not where you're setting it. Are you setting it first?